# Why Do Our Remote Connection Softwares Drop Until DC is rebooted?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, dhcp, domain-controller, rdp

I have been having a recurring issue (1-50 times/week!) where all employees using a remote connection software drop out at the same time and cannot reconnect until I reboot the DC (i.e. They get a "connection lost" message in the software and it continues to behave as though there were no internet connection on the other end). During this time, users connecting on traditional RDP do NOT disconnect. Users in the office itself don't notice any issues at all. I have used a number of network diagnostics (auvik, PRTG, and my RMM tools) and there have been almost no errors at all. Seems to be no events of substance on the DC either.

I adopted the config here and want to move out of it once I can, but right now this is the situation:

-DHCP on Firewall (I moved it there as a hail mary, no effect)

-HyperV Server hosting 2 VM: the DC, and Shares Apps/files (Win Server 2016)

-DC runs DNS/AD (Win Server 2016)

-Approximately 15 (5 RDP/10 other) remote users and 15 in office

Those are all the major details, but at this point the only real clue I can find is that restarting the DC fixes the issue temporarily. Obviously, doing this 5+ times a day can't even be called duct tape. It is very difficult to pin anything else down since it is intermittent and unpredictable.

Comment: Is the DC really just a DC or does it provide other services?

Comment: DC has AD, DNS, RDP, RDP gateway

Comment: What is this software?

Comment: The most used report work software we have is Splashtop

Comment: **all employees using a remote connection software drop out at the same time and cannot reconnect until I reboot the DC** - What does that mean exactly? What drops out? What are the symptoms? What have you looked at?

Comment: @joeqwerty They get a "connection lost" message in the software (splashtop) and it continues to behave as though there were no internet connection on the other end.